# auto-py-to-exe keeps initializing and doesn’t stop

Tags: auto-py-to-exe

auto-py-to-exe keeps initializing, have closed and opened it same thing, have rebooted my system but same thing, doesn’t allow me click on browse to select the python file I want to convert to exe

I tried opening it using command prompt auto-py-to-exe it opens the new window but keeps initializing

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall chrome and use the default browser of the system, that worked for me, you are welcome

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).